# MySQL Query for RFM Analysis

Tags: mysql, case

I have a table with user/order data for RFM analysis.
Sample:

```
+------+---------+--------+------------+
| id_o | user_id | price  | o_date     |
+---------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4491 |  544    | 100.00 | 2016-01-01 |
| 4494 |  642    | 200.00 | 2016-03-01 |
| 4497 |  596    |  50.00 | 2017-01-10 |
+---------+---------+--------+---------+
```

I am trying to write a query that will select and group the users and the amount they spent and categorize them by RFM. So far I have:

```
SELECT user_id, id_o, price,
CASE WHEN price < 100 THEN '3'
     WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 THEN '2'
     ELSE '3'
END AS M,

CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, o_date, DATE('2019-01-01')) < 30 THEN '1'
     WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, o_date, DATE('2019-01-01')) >= 30 AND
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, o_date, DATE('2019-01-01')) < 60 THEN '2'
     ELSE '3'
END AS R

FROM orders;
```

This query gives a table of every order, the amount spent on it and the marked R and M dimensions. However, I also need to add the F dimension, which can be done as the number of orders per user. I tried to add another CASE statement to the query and grouping by user_id, so it looks like this:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(price),
CASE WHEN price < 100 THEN '3'
     WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 THEN '2'
     ELSE '3'
END AS M,

CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, o_date, DATE('2019-01-01')) < 30 THEN '1'
     WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, o_date, DATE('2018-01-01')) >= 30 AND
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, o_date, DATE('2018-01-01')) < 60 THEN '2'
     ELSE '3'
END AS R,

CASE WHEN COUNT(id_o) > 20 THEN '1'
     WHEN COUNT(id_o) > 10 AND COUNT(id_o) <= 20 THEN '2'
     ELSE '3'
END AS F

FROM orders GROUP BY user_id;
```

However, this does not work. Any advice on how to fix this or what I'm missing would be very useful. Is CASE even the right tool for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned the existing working query into a nested query and put the additional CASE statement on top of it, and added a GROUP BY clause. This got me:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(price) AS 'Total Sum', R, M, COUNT(Orders.id_o),
  CASE WHEN COUNT(Orders.id_o) < 2 THEN "3"
       WHEN COUNT(Orders.id_o) >=2 AND COUNT(id_o) <4 THEN "2"
       ELSE "1" 
  END AS F
FROM 
(SELECT user_id, id_o, price,
CASE WHEN price < 100 THEN '3'
     WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 THEN '2'
     ELSE '3'
END AS M,

CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, o_date, DATE('2019-01-01')) < 30 THEN '1'
     WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, o_date, DATE('2019-01-01')) >= 30 AND
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, o_date, DATE('2019-01-01')) < 60 THEN '2'
     ELSE '3'
END AS R

FROM orders) AS Orders
GROUP BY user_id;
```

This returns a table like the following (LIMIT 3):

```
+---------+-----------+------+---+--------------------+---+
| user_id | Total Sum | R    | M | COUNT(Orders.id_o) | F |
+---------+-----------+------+---+--------------------+---+
|       0 |    400.00 | 3    | 2 |                  1 | 3 |
|       1 |     90.00 | 3    | 3 |                  2 | 2 |
|      76 |     80.00 | 3    | 3 |                  2 | 2 |
+---------+-----------+------+---+--------------------+---+
```

Hopefully, this will be useful to others as well.